# Instant object initialization in C++ fails with LNK2005 error

Tags: c++, linker-errors, header-files

These are the errors that I've been receiving:

```
LNK2005 "class Sally TestObject" (?TestObject@@3VSally@@A) already defined in Source.obj    Project2    c:\Users\W8User\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project2\Project2\Source1.obj
```

and

```
LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  Project2    c:\users\w8user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe
```

I don't really understand where are these errors coming from. I've tried searching in other SO threads or on the connected Microsoft's website, but none helped.

These are my files:

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

int main() {

    std::cout << TestObject.ReturnTruth();

    return 0;
}
```

**Header.h**

```
#pragma once

class Sally
{
public:

    bool ReturnTruth();

} TestObject;
```

**Source1.cpp**

```
#include "Header.h"

bool Sally::ReturnTruth()
{
    return 1;
}
```

What I know is that it's enough to move the object initialization into the Source.cpp file and not do it instantly in the header file, but since the instant initialization is a possibility then why wouldn't I use it?

Comment: What do you mean by "instant initialization", and why do you think this should work?

Comment: You have an object **definition** (of `TestObject`) in a header file. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have two different .cpp files that each include your `Header.h` header. Then, each one of those .cpp files gets this code incorporated into it:

```
class Sally
{
public:

    bool ReturnTruth();

} TestObject;
```

As a result, each file contains the definition of an object named `TestObject` of type `Sally`. This breaks the one-definition rule, since there's only supposed to be at most one definition of each object across all translation units, and it's manifesting in your linker error.

If you do want to declare a global object of type `Sally`, change the header to declare an `extern` object of type `Sally`, like this:

```
class Sally
{
public:

    bool ReturnTruth();

};
extern Sally TestObject;
```

This is a *declaration*, not a *definition*, and it's okay to have redundant declarations of objects.

Then, pick a .cpp file - probably the one where you implement the `Sally` member functions - and add this line:

```
Sally TestObject;
```

That puts the *definition* of the object in a single place, and so fixes the one-definition-rule issue and the linker issue.

Comment: Is there any difference between using an extern class object and declaring it in the source file AND just declaring it in the source file without any type of in-header file declaration?

Comment: Yes - if you just declare it in the source file, then it's not visible to anything outside of that source file. If that's what you want to do, I'd take things a step further and wrap the declaration of `TestObject` in an anonymous namespace to ensure no one else can access it.

Comment: @templatetypedef: may be "not visible" is misleading, since every "global" variable in a source file that is not static (or in an anonymous namespace) is accessible and therefore "visible".

Comment: @StephanLechner That's a great point. I think the best *intuitive* explanation would be "not visible *by default*" for that reason, even though that's not technically the precise term.

Answer (score 0):

Every single place you `#include "Header.h"` you will have an instance of `TestObject`, and unless your compiler can fold all of these into a singleton you're going to have several independent, unrelated instances.

That error is advising you that you've made a mistake. One way to fix this is to define in the header file:

```
extern Sally TestObject;
```

Which makes it explicitly clear that this will be instantiated elsewhere. Then make an explicit instance in `Source1.cpp`:

```
Sally TestObject;
```

Then your main file will know where to look for this thing.

It's not clear if you want a singleton in the first place. Why can't you just instantiate one inside of `main` and use it?

As a note, please, **please** take the time to give your source files meaningful names.

Comment: Is there any difference between using an extern class object and declaring it in the source file AND just declaring it in the source file without any type of in-header file declaration? Oh and I'm aware that the files should have meaningful names, these are just the first names that came up in the IDE. Normally I don't use them, this time I did it to show an error that would happen anyway.

Comment: If you declare it just inside the source file that limits that instance to the scope of your file, it can't be accessed outside of that unless you've defined some kind of interface to it, such as a method that's described in a header file. As for the names, something like `(untitled).cpp` can and will give people an angry rash, so please keep your questions clean and uncluttered with nonsense like that. It helps avoid distractions.

Answer (score 0):

By appending identifier `TestObject` directly after the class definition `Sally`, you define a variable in your header file. So if different translation units include this header file, a variable with the same name is defined twice, leading to a linker error. You can resolve this by just *declaring*  the variable, i.e. using `extern`-keyword in the headerfile, whereas *defining* the variable then in exactly one `.cpp`-file:

So write:

**Header.h**

```
class Sally
{
public:

    bool ReturnTruth();

};

extern Sally TestObject;
```

**Source1.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

Sally TestObject;
...
```

**in all other CPP-files:**

```
#include "header.h"
...
```

Comment: Is there any difference between using an extern class object and declaring it in the source file AND just declaring it in the source file without any type of in-header file declaration?

Comment: @Suiko: No, except that one would have to "guess" that there is such a variable in some translation unit. But actually every variable that is defined in a translation unit and that is not marked "static" or defined in an anonymous namespace is visible to other translation units; Note that `extern Sally Testobject` just gives the compiler the information that there will be such an object in another translation unit (then only the linker will complain if not).